# receiver type mismatch in Kotlin with Android's `activityViewModels`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewmodel

Haven't touched Android in years, and not really Kotlin at all. My [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) has one of these:

```kotlin
package com.example.my_frag

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import com.example.MainViewModel


class MyFragViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels<MainViewModel>()
}
```

For completion, here is the [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment):

```kotlin
package com.example.my_frag

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.R


class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var myFragViewModel: MyFragViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        myFragViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyFragViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false)
        return root
    }
}
```

…and my [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) looks like:

```kotlin
package com.example

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel.selectedItem.observe(this, Observer { item ->
            println("$item observed")
        })
    }
}
```

With the [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) being:

```kotlin
package com.example

import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel


class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mutableSelectedItem = MutableLiveData<MenuItem>()
    val selectedItem: LiveData<MenuItem> get() = mutableSelectedItem

    fun selectItem(item: MenuItem) {
        mutableSelectedItem.value = item
    }
}
```

I was careful to add to my `build.gradle` these `dependencies`:

```groovy
dependencies {
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

However it doesn't work, [`activityViewModels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#activityviewmodels) is highlighted red and the error is:

> **Unresolved reference**. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
> `public inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.activityViewModels(noinline factoryProducer: (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = ...): Lazy<TypeVariable(VM)>` defined in `androidx.fragment.app`

How do I use this pattern?

Comment: why do you call `by activityViewModels<MainViewModel>()` in the ViewModel and not in the corresponding Fragment? When I instantiate like this in the Fragment I don't have any issues

Comment: @Stachu - I added the `Fragment` example so you get the fuller picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels<MainViewModel>()
```

should go in your Fragment class, not your other ViewModel class. `activityViewModels()` is a function of Fragment, not ViewModel. ViewModels should not reference each other. They are scoped to the lifecycle of an Activity or Fragment and don't have their own capital-L Lifecycle that another ViewModel can attach to.

Comment: I've got tabbed navigation, and some buttons in the navbar (consistent no matter which tab). If I want to handle the navbar button click differently—and locally [in frag class or frag viewmodel]—depending on the active fragment, is this the "right" pattern?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. Typically the ViewModel class just provides hooks for retrieving and modifying data and has no awareness of specific UI components. You don’t have to use it that way but a ViewModel scoped to an Activity definitely shouldn’t reference any components of a Fragment or it will leak the Fragment.

Comment: Hey so I played around with that, and not only did the `Unresolved reference` error disappear, but this observer syntax worked - `mainViewModel.selectedItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,  {` (in fragment) and `viewModel.selectedItem.observe(this, {` in the activity. - Great! - +1 and accepted